# YourKit showing 16 MB byte[] being allocated when WebSocket client connects to WebSocket server

Tags: websocket, netty

I'm using the Netty beta 2 websocket functionality in a java 7 se embedded app where I'm trying to make the footprint as small as possible.  I'm running with -Xms8m and -Xmx32m.

When I profile the app in YourKit, as soon as the client establishes the websocket channel with the server, the fundamental byte[] type size jumps from 2 MB to 16 MB.

- NOTE: this is after the handshake, but before any websocket message is sent

Has anyone else seen this and do you know what is doing this allocation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this happens because of our pooled ByteBufAllocator that is used in Netty 4 by default. It will allocate big chunks of byte put it in the pool and use only "slices" of it when request smaller sizes. This helps with memory layout on the heap etc.

If you want to have low-memory usage (and loose some performance) use the unpooled ByteBufAllocator.

For clients:

```
bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, UnpooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT);
```

For Servers:

```
bootstrap.childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, UnpooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: In general, we want to use all the max-performance/throughput options, but in this case, memory footprint is definitely a consideration.  Thanks for the tip, Norman.